# Mysql query across three tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a site that allows users to upload posters of television productions they have made. Other users can add themselves to the posters if they were involved with the production and their names get listed below the poster too.

I am having problems writing a mysql query that will allow me to list all the uploaded posters but also any of the users that have listed themselves as being involved with the production. I have made this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34952/16) that might help. The current query displays all the uploaded posters but not those who have added themselves to the poster. Any ideas?

The query

```
 SELECT tbl_uploads.file_name, tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.user_name, tbl_collab.collab_userid, tbl_collab.collab_username
  FROM tbl_uploads

left join tbl_collab  on tbl_collab.file_name = tbl_uploads.file_name

 left join tbl_users on  tbl_uploads.user_id = tbl_users.user_id
group by tbl_uploads.file_name
```

The tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(60) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_users` (`user_id`, `user_name`,`user_email`) VALUES
(2, 'julian', 'julian@email.com'),
(3, 'bob', 'bob@email.com'),
(4, 'sue', 'sue@email.com');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_uploads` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_uploads` (`id`, `file_name`, `user_id`) VALUES 
('7', 'Julians Picture','2' ),
('13', 'Julians 2nd picture','2' ),
('14', 'Bobs Picture','3' ),
('15', 'Another Picture','3' );


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_collab` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `collab_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `collab_userid` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_collab` (`id`,`file_name`,`collab_userid`, `user_id`,`collab_username`) VALUES ('1','Bobs Picture','4','4','Sue' ), ('2','Another Picture','3','3','Bob' )
,('3','Bobs Picture','2','2','Julian' );
```

Comment: You want to see all the `collab` entries, yet you group your results by the upload. Unfortunately MySQL is forgiving enough not to throw an error, but by grouping you are omitting all but the first (I am not sure if it even really is the first or just any) result for each upload. Just remove the `GROUP BY` line and you should be fine. Have a look at this for more: https://blog.jooq.org/2012/08/05/mysql-bad-idea-384/

Comment: I still can't figure out how to correctly right an sql query that doesn't produce duplicates despite following your advice.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? Of course the same `file_name` will appear multiple times if there are several entries for it in the collab table. But that is exactly what you asked for, to get all collaborators. Please update your question with the expected output to make it clearer what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did what I was looking for. `GROUP_CONCAT` did the trick

```
SELECT up.file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.collab_username)
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file_name = c.file_name
GROUP BY up.file_name
```